# unconverted data remains: .387000 in Python

Tags: python, strftime, strptime

I have a datetime that is a string I read from a text file.  I want to trim the extra milliseconds off of it, but I want to convert it to a datetime variable first.  This is because it may be in different formats depending on what is in the text file.  How ever, everything I have tried wants me to already know the format.  Please take a look at what I am trying here:

```
import time, datetime

mytime = "2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000"
myTime = time.strptime(mytime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

myFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.strptime(mytime, myFormat)))
```

But this gives me this error:

```
File "python", line 10, in <module>
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .387000`
```

Can someone please tell me how to do a normal datetime format?  In other languages I can pass in various formats and then set it to a new format without a problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are doing it backwards. Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

mytime = "2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000"
myTime = datetime.strptime(mytime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

myFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

print "Original", myTime
print "New", myTime.strftime(myFormat)
```

result:

```
Original 2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000
New 2015-02-16 10:36:41
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to reference microseconds in `myFormat`

```
myFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
```

Anyway, you can convert it with less steps

```
from datetime import datetime

mytime = "2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000"
full = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
myTime = datetime.strptime(mytime, full)
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 10, 36, 41, 387000)
```

Here `mytime` is in `datetime` object. If you want print without microseconds, use the `strftime`

```
myfmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
print datetime.strptime(mytime, full).strftime(myfmt)
>>> 2015-02-16 10:36:41
```

Comment: That actually creates a string not a datetime object which is what the OP's code is trying to do

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution is using split():

```
# mytime is str(timestamp)
datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mytime = "2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000 "

myTime = time.strptime(mytime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

->

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:

it is my case, and what I need is `mytime.strip()`

Answer (score -1):

If nothing else is changing, i.e. the format, except that you are dropping the micro seconds at the end, you don't really need to call strftime.  You can just substring it:

```
mytime = "2015-02-16 10:36:41.387000"
mytime = mytime[:-7]    
print mytime
```

result:

```
2015-02-16 10:36:41
```

Disclaimer:  This is only be applicable if you do not to re-format or rearrange anything, and only if you are trying to drop the last bit.

Comment: its too crude for me (11M rows of data), but this is the only answer for ignoring data